# How to add find query in cakephp2.4 while loading a component using fly

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

How to import components in cakephp on the fly.

I am importing the component in my controller using:

```
            // -----------------------------
            // load component and action
            // -----------------------------

            $this->ThingToDo = $this->Components->load($ComponentName);
            $WhatToReturn    = $this->ThingToDo->$ActionName();
```

I am not able to add the find condition in the component. I want to find the records from the plugin created. so to fetch the result I have include the model on the top of the function

var $uses = array('PaypalIpn.PaypalInstantPaymentNotification');

and  following is the code i have written in component file:-

```
function  processnotifcation(){
 $fetchNotificationDetail = $this->PaypalInstantPaymentNotification->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array(
                'id',
                'ProcessedTimeStamp',
                'ProcessedComment',
                'txn_type'
            ),
            'order' => 'id desc',
            'conditions' => array(
                "ProcessedTimeStamp" => '0'
            )
        ));
pr( $fetchNotificationDetail); die;
}
```

but it throws an error that `find()` is not a function.

Can anybody tell me how to use find() in component file?

Comment: You can use classRegistry::init() to create the object of that model and use find()  function to fetch result.

Comment: But if we taken in to consideration MVC design pattern then it is bad practice to write find query in component so move it in to particular model if possible.